# Who carries something ending in -ium?

Tags: adjective, derivation

There is a traditional Finnish instrument (*kannel* or *kantele*) which tends to be called *nablium* in Latin.
How do I form the adjective for someone bearing this instrument using *-fer*?
There are things like *ensifer* and *lucifer* and others, but I failed to find an example derived from a noun ending in *-ium*.

My intuition says it should be simply *nablifer*, but I am far from sure that *nabliifer* or some other construction should be used with such words.
I do not expect to see *nablifer* as such attested anywhere, but I am happy to reason by analogy if I can see something analogous.

I assume a similar reasoning would apply to most words ending in *-ius/-ia/-ium/-eus/-ea/-eum*, but the actual question at hand concerns *-ium*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, [*laserpicifer*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlaserpicifer) from [*laserpicium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlaserpicium) and [*caducifer*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcaducifer) from [*caduceus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dcaduceus) exist, so I think you're on solid ground.